# How to edit ListView item when double clicked in JavaFX?

Tags: listview, javafx, edit, desktop-application

I have a ListView containing note headers for my note app. I use a new window to enable user to edit the header. But I would like to make it possible for user to just double click that cell of the listview and write the new header without opening a new window or dialog. Is it possible? How can I achieve that?

Comment: Use  [`TextFieldListCell`s](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldListCell.html) as the cells in the `ListView`.

Comment: what's the problem, exactly? that's standard behavior, given the list is editable and you have a cell as f.i. the one suggested by @James_D (as any reasonable tutorial would tell you ..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As James_D commented you can use TextFieldListCell, but if you want more granular control, then I would recommend a [custom cell factory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#cellFactoryProperty)